# Unresolved reference: ConcatAdapter

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

My code line is the following and I'm getting the error
**Unresolved reference: ConcatAdapter**
I already tried with MergeAdapter and it's still not working.

`val concatAdapter = ConcatAdapter(headerAdapter, itemsAdapter)`

Any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have RecyclerView 1.2.0 in your grade file?

It was released in that version https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview#version_120_3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).